# How to convert google datastore format to integer/number

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers

How do I convert the data stored in google datastore to its original numerical format?

Currently saving data to google datastore through IoT, where the original data looks like:

```
CO2 438 gm3 3/18/19 at 10:13:48 am

CO2 436 gm3 3/18/19 at 10:12:43 am

CO2 438 gm3 3/18/19 at 10:11:38 am

CO2 438 gm3 3/18/19 at 10:10:33 am

CO2 439 gm3 3/18/19 at 10:09:28 am

CO2 440 gm3 3/18/19 at 10:08:23 am
```

and the Pub/sub data structure looks like

```
 { gc_pub_sub_id: '312422947136384',

  device_id: '38001c000851363136363935',

  event: 'CO2',

  **data: <Buffer 34 34 32>,**

  published_at: '2019-03-18T09:14:53.711Z' }
```

the final data looks like

```
id=5639047607222272     NDQz    38001c000851363136363935    CO2     312423130805644     2019-03-18T09:15:58.764Z    

id=5069056390463488     NDQy    38001c000851363136363935    CO2     312422947136384     2019-03-18T09:14:53.711Z 

..
```

and so the data i.e. 438 is converted to NDQz. My question is, how do I convert NDQz to its original numerical format, 438?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format was Base64 and the stored data was able to be converted to the original numerical format.

Comment: As far as I understand you found the solution to your question. If this was helpful to you, please accept your answer as solution to give more visibility to the question.

Comment: Yes, but I have to wait 21 hours more